# Kali linux freezes after injection

Tags: kali-linux, airmon-ng, aircrack-ng

When I execute the command aireplay-ng, the OS freezes totally, and the only way to "fix it" is rebooting.

Any solution?

Platform: Kali Linux
Wifi Card: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377
GUI: No, I use the terminal
I do this process:

```
airmon-ng check kill 
airmon-ng start wlan0
airodump-ng wlan0mon
airodump-ng -c {no channel} --bssid {bssid} -write WPAcrack wlan0mon
aireplay-ng -0 5 -a {BSSID} -c {BSSID Client} wlan0mon
```

Comment: @G-Man not necessarily (although it _is_ tempting). Looks like we're getting some useful information now.

Comment: Concur with @roaima. This does appear to be someone using Kali as the tool it's meant to be, just something going wrong when they try it.

Comment: Can you confirm which Kali kernel you are running and also the supported interface modes on your card (output from `iw list`)

Comment: @Oten Also can you confirm the firmware / drivers you are using, firmware-atheros I assume.